# GXT: Rest data on Window close event

Tags: window, gxt

I have a window I've created using UiBinder. I'm followings Sencha's HelloWorldUiBinder example and have placed a form inside the window. I wanted to know how to reset the form data after the widow has bee closed(hiden)?

Comment: [have you tried anything](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. All I did was add all of my fields to a List, then looped through that list in my closeWindow handler. Calling the rest() method. That clears all the data from my fields. I just need to figure out how to get my Radio buttons to select the default options when the window is reopened.

The code looks like this:

```
@UiHandler("closeButton")
public void onCloseButtonClicked(SelectEvent event){
       for(Field<?> f : fields){
           f.rest();
       }
       window.hide();
}
```